# Adding real-time chat messaging to my SwiftUI app: What options are available?

Tags: swiftui, sdk, chat, messaging, instant-messaging

I am building a SwiftUI app that will have an in-app chat messaging functionality. Is there any SwiftUI SDK I can use to add the chat functionality?

Answer (score 0):

### One option is [**Stream**](https://getstream.io).

They have iOS SDKs for both [UIKit](https://getstream.io/chat/sdk/ios/) and [SwiftUI](https://getstream.io/chat/sdk/swiftui/) and provide good samples on how to implement and customize their SDK.

Comment: that is an excellent option. but they are too expensive.